# How to put 2 embed YouTube iframes in a row?

Tags: html, css, iframe, css-position, display

I have trouble positioning these 2 YouTube iframes side by side in a row.

```css
.video-section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}

.videos {
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.videos iframe {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-section">
  <div class="videos first-video">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/78bXV1ZqQWI">
      </div>

      <div class="videos second-video">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oAQxk9dOJ8k">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here it's showing only the first iframe and does not showing the second one:
[image]

And when I remove the first iframe it shows like that:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03O3l.png)

Comment: I put your code in the editor's snippet tool and it was immediately apparent that your HTML was faulty. A good editor will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `iframe` tags are missing their closing `</iframe>` tags. It seems to work fine once you add the closing tags.

Note that the actual YouTube videos don't show up in Stack Overflow code sandbox environment. I tested it in CodePen and confirmed that both videos show up.

```css
.video-section{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
}

.videos{
    width: 40%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.videos iframe{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
   <div class="video-section">
      <div class="videos first-video">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/78bXV1ZqQWI"></iframe>
      </div>

      <div class="videos second-video">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oAQxk9dOJ8k"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It would also be helpful to let the OP know about nested iframes.  One cannot be nested in the other, as the <iframe> has an independent DOM that will overwrite anything inside the block.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing `</iframe>` tags.

```
 <div class="video-section">
      <div class="videos first-video">
        <iframe  height="100%"  frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/78bXV1ZqQWI"></iframe>
      </div>

      <div class="videos second-video">
        <iframe height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oAQxk9dOJ8k"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
```